# How to Update or Change Camera Position between two Locations using GoogleMaps GMSCamera in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

In viewDidLoad I give my current Location to show in Map.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
strForCurLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
strForCurLongitude= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
GMSCameraUpdate  *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coor zoom:14];
[mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
```

But after that I have two text fields when I give two different locations in two text fields textFieldDidEndEditing then the camera did not move or update or change position to that location in google maps, here I give the code what I am tried but it did not worked.

```
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera;
if(textField==self.txtAddress)
{        
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;
    coor.latitude=[strForLatitude doubleValue];
    coor.longitude=[strForLongitude doubleValue];
    pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pref setObject:strForLatitude forKey:@"Pickup_Latitude"];
    [pref setObject:strForLongitude forKey:@"Pickup_Longitude"];
    [pref synchronize];
    updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coor zoom:14];
    [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
}
if(textField==self.txtDropoffAddress)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor;
    coor.latitude=[[pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Latitude"] doubleValue];
    coor.longitude=[[pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Longitude"] doubleValue];
    updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coor zoom:14];
    [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
}
```

Please help me to fix this..

Comment: what you want to do??

Comment: are you get the value in here `pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Latitude"`

Comment: You are assigning value for pref in first if condition `pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` and trying to get values from it in second if condition `[[pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Latitude"] doubleValue];`

Comment: Where and how are you setting value for key `Destination_Latitude` and `Destination_Longitude`?

Comment: @nikdange_me I edit and update my question.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR globally stored value for Destination_Longitude.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I get the value for coor.latitude from pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Latitude"

Comment: Try to `NSLog` `coor.latitude` and `coor. longitude` before `animateWithCameraUpdate`

Comment: @saravanakumar do you want to show both coordinate or single only??

Comment: @nikdange_me I want to show the location based on text field when I end edit txtAddress or txtDropoffAddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried something using GMSCameraPosition fix the problem.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField==self.txtAddress  && self.txtAddress.text.length > 0)
{  
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: [strForLatitude doubleValue]
                                                            longitude: [strForLongitude doubleValue] zoom: 14];
    [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition: camera];
    [CATransaction commit];
    self.ImageMarkerMapCentre.hidden = NO;
}

if(textField==self.txtDropoffAddress  && self.txtDropoffAddress.text.length > 0)
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[[pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[pref objectForKey:@"Destination_Longitude"] doubleValue] zoom:14];
    [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition: camera];
    [CATransaction commit];
    self.ImageMarkerMapCentre.hidden = YES;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your explanation; anything else required then suggest.

Extend your class with UITextFieldDelegate:

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And add this method :

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
          if((textField==self.txtAddress || textField==self.txtDropoffAddress) && (self.txtAddress.length > 0 && self.txtDropoffAddress.length>0))
          {
          // Your code to change position 
          }
```